# How can I align on nested braces (NEWBIE)

Tags: vertical-alignment, mathtools, cases

In texStudio basically the following code returns the expected result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[japanese]{babel}

\begin{document}
    
    \[ \begin{rcases}
        \begin{rcases}
            \begin{alignedat}{2}
                V \\[-1.5ex]                
                \\[-1.25ex]
                I -adj
            \end{alignedat}
        \end{rcases}
        % Jisho \\
        \text{Jisho}\\
        \begin{rcases}
            \begin{alignedat}{2}
                NA -adj \\[-1.5ex]
                 \\[-1.25ex]
                N1
            \end{alignedat}
        \end{rcases}
        \begin{split}
            Jisho\\Trans
        \end{split}
    \end{rcases}
    \text{Result}
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the two braces left are not aligned.
Is it possible to align on the brace-symbol?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[japanese]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\[ 
\setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.33}
\left.
\begin{array}{rr}
  \left.\begin{array}{r} 
    V \\ I-adj 
  \end{array}\right\} & 
      \multicolumn{1}{l}{\text{Jisho}} \\
  \addlinespace
  \left.\begin{array}{r} 
    NA-adj \\ N1 
  \end{array}\right\} &
      \begin{array}{r} 
         Jisho \\ Trans 
      \end{array}
\end{array}
\right\}
\text{Result}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: In response to this code, I began a focused search. Is it true that the dot in '\left.' (line 12) is essential to the solution?
And is it also a correct assumption that lines 8-11 define an environment that is then used for the first time in line 12? Where should I look for information about this construction?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: @BenEngbers - In TeX and LaTeX, a `\left. ...right\}` construct means "no large delimiter on the left and a large curly brace on the right". So, yes, the `.` is essential in all three instances of `\left.`. The `\left.` instruction on line 10 is associated with the `\right\}` on line -5 (i.e., the fifth from the bottom). Do please check out the posting [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001)