# How can I change the Japanese font to be used (NEWBIE)

Tags: fonts, japanese

I edited the code as provided by Mico (see [Align on nested braces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/697478/how-can-i-align-on-nested-braces-newbie)) and managed to change the font to be used for the Latin characters to 'nimbus sans'.
Using TexStudio and the latex compiler, the following code returns exactly what I want. The only remaining problem is that I don't know how I can change the Japanese font to be used.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,booktabs} 
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{nimbussans}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}    
    \[ 
    \setlength\arraycolsep{0pt}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1}
    \left.
    \begin{array}{rr}
        \left.\begin{array}{r} 
            \text{V} \\ \text{い-adj} 
        \end{array}\right\} & 
        \multicolumn{1}{r}{\text{Jisho}} \\
        \addlinespace
        \left.\begin{array}{r} 
            \text{な-adj} \\ \text{N}\textsubscript{1}
        \end{array}\right\} &
        \begin{array}{r} 
            \text{Jisho} \\ \text{$\sim$\cancel{だ}}\to\text{$\sim$な} 
        \end{array}
    \end{array}
    \right\}    
    \text{のは N}\textsubscript{2}\text{です}
    \]
\end{CJK*}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

All my LibreOffice documents use Noto Sans mono CJK JP as the default font. Is it possible to use the same font in Latex?

Comment: you can use any opentype font including Noto Sans if you use lualatex rather than pdflatex (so not T1 encoding)

Comment: The real Noto Sans Mono is not (easily) available for pdflatex/latex (and very easily for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, as David commented). However, depending on your installation there are probably some variants available for pdflatex/latex that look a bit more sans. For example instead of `gbsn` you could try `goth` or `maru`. I don't know if they have all the required characters available for Japanese though.

Comment: After switching to lualatex, the Japanese characters were no longer displayed. 
Where can I find information on how to install opentype fonts? And what means 'gbsn', 'goth' or 'maru'? ( I am really a Newbie on latex).

Comment: gbsn is a font for simplified Chinese, goth is a Gothic Japanese font, maru is a Maru Gothic font (see https://tex.my/2010/06/21/cjk-support-in-latex/). To be clear, you can use `goth` and `maru` in your code above on the 11th line, so instead of `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}` what you have now you could use `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{goth}` or `\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{maru}` to get different fonts. Despite the name 'Gothic' the two alternatives are actually simpler/cleaner than gbsn, they look more 'sans-achtig', zogezegd.

Comment: I removed the [T1] encoding and replaced gbsn with goth. After compiling I can see that another font is used. Only a pity that Noto Sans mono CJK JP is much easier to read. How can I use Noto Sans mono when using lualatex? (ik ben nieuwsgierig, zogezegd)

Comment: Later on, for reference, you can investigate Japanese-specific packages/unicode (e.g., do `texdoc luatexja-en`) rather than staying with old coding and legacy fonts etc.