# Where can I specify in Luatex-Ja the ttc-file that should be used?

Tags: fonts, luatexja, linuxfedora

I'm using Fedora 38. And for editing Japanese texts, I use the Google Noto fonts. In LibreOffice, using those fonts gives no problems. However, in LuaTex-Ja, I cannot manage to use the Noto Sans Mono CJK font.

In response to previous questions (see [How can I use Noto Sans mono CJK iN LuaTex-Ja? (NEWBIE)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/699080/how-can-i-use-noto-sans-mono-cjk-in-luatex-ja-newbie?noredirect=1#comment1737331_699080)) [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) told me that the following command `fc-match "Noto Serif CJK JP"` should return `NotoSerifCJK-Regular.ttc: "Noto Serif CJK JP" "Regular"`. However, on my PC the same command returns  `NotoSerifCJK-VF.ttc: "Noto Serif CJK JP" "Regular"`.
I uninstalled all google-noto-sans-mono-cjk-vf-fonts and google-noto-serif-mono-cjk-vf-fonts and then reinstalled google-noto-sans-cjk-jp-fonts google-noto-serif-cjk-jp-fonts. But fc-match still returns the same answer.

How can I fix this? In which Luatex-Ja file can I set the correct filename, or do I have to manually create a new ttc-file?

Comment: you shouldn't edit any of the luatex-ja files, just specify the font (via filename or internal font name) in your document. note lualatex does not use fontconfig but its font search path should include your standard font directories. Perhaps the problem is you have the -vf (variable font) versions but hard to tell just from the above.

Comment: I tried to prevent the installation of the vf variant of the fontfiles but despite the choice of `sudo dnf install google-noto-sans-cjk-jp-fonts`, google-noto-sans-mono-cjk-vf-fonts was eventually installed.  
I will try to use the fonts via filename or internal font name.

Comment: I didn't say you should necessarily get the same output. I just meant the output could help you to identify which of the various `noto` presets would work with the fonts you had installed.

Comment: None of the noto presets work. ;-(  . They all complain that NotoSansCJKJP* fonts can not be found. My suspicion that the bug is related to the absence of NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc is growing. I will submit a bug report to Fedora. Maybe they know a solution.

Comment: According to the page you linked, you don't need to dig up old packages. The alternative non-vf packages are still available, but they are no longer default. Unless that update note is outdated and they've since been removed?

Comment: If you submit a bug, please add the link into your answer or question. It's worth reporting even if suitable packages are available as non-default, I think. I guess the question is whose bug it is.

Answer (score 0):

Since in Fedora 38 the use of the static Google-noto CJK fonts is no longer supported, I went looking for old rpm files for CJK. In doing so, I quickly found the following page that clarifies why only Variable Fonts are still installed. [Changes/Noto CJK Variable Fonts](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Noto_CJK_Variable_Fonts)

Then by successively searching at `https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=` for google-noto-cjk-fonts-common, google-noto-sans-cjk-jp-fonts, google-noto-sans-mono-cjk-jp-fonts and google-noto-serif-cjk-jp-fonts I found the sought RPM files.
After removing the previously installed fonts (sudo dnf erase google-noto-sans-cjk-vf-fonts google-noto-serif-cjk-vf-fonts) and installing the RPM files I finally managed to successfully compile the MWE.
The command `fc-match "Noto Serif CJK JP"` now returns `NotoSansCJKjp-Regular.otf: "Noto Sans CJK JP" "Regular"`. So my suspicion that the problem was related to the missing ttc or otf file turned out to be correct.

Thanks everyone for the help and I learned a lot about using fonts.

UPDATE
The command `sudo dnf update` tries to update the CJK-fonts to the newer cjk-vf fonts. This can be prevented by adding the following line to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`:
`exclude=google-noto-cjk-fonts-common google-noto-sans-cjk-jp-fonts google-noto-serif-cjk-vf-fonts`
Execution of the dnf command gives a warning but the font files are not updated